# Video NFTs - Broken Video Links

Tags: nft

Is there a known issue right now with mint for mp4 files? All the tokens show broken links in my phantom wallet and all Solana Explorers. I am using devnet currently.

Comment: Here is a URL to the an example transaction: https://solana.fm/address/4fTMMqR7CGCaHVbKsz8xyr9GbYqJSgUDQYLSNrDXDuw2?cluster=devnet-solana

Comment: Normally MP4 files are hosted on arweave or some other location rather than on Solana's blockchain - have you checked the address of the .mp4 file?